Horror movie about an old woman and a couple
So the movie starts off with an old Asian woman in the tub committing suicide. Then it switches to this couple looking at the house and eventually buying it. While living there they are constantly getting packages for the old owners and they have creepy messages inside. The woman gets sick and starts losing hair, and getting terrorized by a "birdman"/"crowman".
The wife makes friends with neighbor lady and her special child. The kid liked tree house that was in their backyard. Couple thinks the person responsible for the events was the old Asian man who lived there before.
Towards the end, it was discovered that the neighbor Lady and her son, who isn't actually special child, just fakes it was responsible for the mishappenings. The house the couple moved into was theirs before.
The house was foreclosed on them and the lady saved up for a crap ton of years to finally buy the house. The neighbor lady was also poisoning the wife and that is why she was sick. The lady did it to the old Asian woman as well. She was doing everything she could to get her house back. 

It's The Watcher (2016)
It's an American horror film written and directed by Ryan Rothmaier. It stars Erin Cahill, Edi Gathegi and Denise Crosby.(IMDB)

Plot: (psychodrivein)

A young couple, Noah (Edi Gathegi) and Emma (Erin Cahill), invests all
  of their money into a beautiful fixer upper home. At first, the two
  are on Cloud 9 as they start home repairs and moving in. Shortly
  after, though, it seems that someone or something wants the couple to
  leave. Creepy and threatening notes signed by “The Raven”, along with
  dead ravens keep appearing in their home. The couple is not sure
  whether the former owner is just trying to scare them into moving or
  if the home is haunted. The realtor did disclose that a death occurred
  in the home although she painted it as a peaceful death of an elderly
  woman after a long illness.
Jeanne (Denise Crosby), an older neighbor with a cognitively disabled
son named Mikey, (Riley Baron) befriended Emma, but there is something
  just a little off about her that Noah distrusts.

Trailer




